# Build Errors in Eclipse (Java Project) due to multiple references of the same Java class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have imported a Java project in eclipse. There are a lot of build errors because some of the referenced classes are present in other referenced project as well as in maven repo.Is there a way to fetch the classes from local repo and if unavailable pick from maven (other way around is also fine)?

Comment: If your project is an maven project, then you could import the project as a maven project instead of normal java project in eclipse and it will do all the magic for you. There is an maven plugin for eclipse, use that.

Comment: Thanks Sajan, I did try doing that - but am struck with multiple compliation problems. I guess the application is not built properly. Yet to debug and find the root cause. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try maven command `mvn eclipse:eclipse` which will re-generate your `.project` and `.classpath` files based on Maven dependencies. Make sure you have created a backup of your initial project files.

Comment: I did mvn eclipse:eclipse and imported as maven project. Now the compliation issue are gone and the project is working fine. Thanks!